# Laravel/Homestead up does not open the app with 502 nginx/1.9.7 error

Tags: nginx, homestead, laravel-5

Please, help! 
After I updated vagrant and homestead, the homestead does not bring the page. I have tried to reinstall vagrant, vm, homestead but the same empty page with 502 Bad Gateway and nginx errors continues to come up. This is the code from 'homestead up' command:

```
pavelkrotov$ homestead up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/pavelkrotov/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead
    default: /home/vagrant/Sites => /Users/pavelkrotov/Sites
==> default: Running provisioner: file...
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCepZ6J7i8UruJj/Qvw7j7GFYgLYajrE4GqSUO1tK4o3KFZh1pttt8lHKMqSfR1Ltw4/qA0ZtX2iqTh8INe1zaI8kFooxC0vURyEdzu1OLRvast6AGFXIsY6QXI8/5ayWoRBVPfeaphoO/QlbwaN9hjG/V0ux0dC9gk4vsKKQsxcN+MkEMDLUICYb4X+3AN8G3ROvc6iGae+CDvrwUhbAQy04CLJSmEFYk8Dp4HCEjynuzSynXeQKL2yyAx9aBmjMualREkITxkJ5c9m4TGqEBU3r9yQcxWOJ5m4tEvvjhmW4uSzglxNapD1rt4BqZuuLkM/33A2nRvPixbJHh5VtRp you@homestead
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/0w/tk3pjfvx4jn5bnx1kjdv2hxw0000gn/T/vagrant-shell20160104-29643-12jcfdq.sh
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/0w/tk3pjfvx4jn5bnx1kjdv2hxw0000gn/T/vagrant-shell20160104-29643-5yn8ap.sh
==> default: nginx stop/waiting
==> default: nginx start/running, process 1831
==> default: php5-fpm: unrecognized service
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

What is going on? How to fix the issue? Thanks

Comment: ...Did not realize that homestead 3.0 has different rules from the version 2 and homestead init is not valid any more. I read documentation on Laravel 5 and it helped.